# Use Stop-Transcript to record only input

Tags: windows, powershell, visual-studio-code

I want to use "Start-Transcript" command to record only the input in the VS-Code terminal in windows. Currently it records both input as well as the output. Also is there any better way to record just the input in the VS code terminal?

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to this! I had found `Get-History` (someone beat me to answering) but was wondering (but had yet to look for) something that would capture the output too! Aka, I wanted to do the opposite of you ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Get-History`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-history) to obtain a list of all command lines that were submitted in the current session.

`(Get-History).CommandLine` outputs just the command lines, as strings.

Comment: Alternatively `Get-History | Select-Object -ExpandProperty CommandLine | Out-File C:\path\to\script.ps1` to be more stylish.